# how display the data of stock with the help of user table

Tags: laravel

I stored the User id in Stock table from session user with each row of data. Now i try to retrive the data for particlar user that's loggin at the time. Only which data show in table which row match the user_id with auth user_id.
THis is my index page

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  @if($message = Session::get('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
   <p>{{$message}}</p>
  </div>
  @endif
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title"> Stock
                <div align="right">
   <a href="{{route('stock.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>

  </div></h4>

              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table">
                    <thead class=" text-primary">
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Product code</th>
    <th>deatils</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    @foreach($stocks as $row Auth::user()->user_id == user_if)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$row['product_name']}}</td>
    <td>{{$row['product_code']}}</td>
     <td>{{$row['details']}}</td>
      <td>{{$row['price']}}</td>
       <td>{{$row['cost']}}</td>
        <td>{{$row['quntity']}}</td>
    <td ><a  href="{{action('StockController@edit', $row['id'])}}" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    </td>
    <td>
     <form id="my_form"  method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('StockController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
     </form>
    </td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

THis is my controller file which i try to display data of particular user which is loggin at the time

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Stock;
use Auth;
class StockController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $stocks = Stock::all()->toArray();
        return view('stock.index', compact('stocks'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('stock.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_id' =>'required',
            'product_name'    =>  'required',
            'product_code'     =>  'required',
             'details'    =>  'required',
            'price'     =>  'required',
            'cost'    =>  'required',
            'quntity'     =>  'required'
        ]);
        $stock = new Stock([
            'user_id' =>  $request->get('user_id'),  
           'product_name'    =>  $request->get('product_name'),
            'product_code'    =>  $request->get('product_code'),
            'details'    =>  $request->get('details'),
            'price'    =>  $request->get('price'),
            'cost'    =>  $request->get('cost'),
            'quntity'     =>  $request->get('quntity')
]);
        $stock->save();
        return redirect()->route('stock.index')->with('success', 'Data Added');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
       $stock = Stock::find($id);
        return view('stock.edit', compact('stock', 'id'));
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
             'product_name'    =>  'required',
            'product_code'     =>  'required',
             'details'    =>  'required',
            'price'     =>  'required',
            'cost'    =>  'required',
            'quntity'     =>  'required'
        ]);
        $stock = Stock::find($id);
        $stock->product_name = $request->get('product_name');
        $stock->product_code = $request->get('product_code');
        $stock->details = $request->get('details');
        $stock->price = $request->get('price');
        $stock->cost = $request->get('cost');
        $stock->quntity = $request->get('quntity');
        $stock->save();
        return redirect()->route('stock.index')->with('success', 'Data Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
         $stock = Stock::find($id);
        $stock->delete();
        return redirect()->route('stock.index')->with('success', 'Data Deleted');
    }
}
```

Comment: @foreach($stocks as $row Auth::user()->user_id == user_if) there is maybe typo in the user_if

Comment: You need to set up a relationship between User and Stock. Follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships). Then just call `Auth::user()->stocks` instead of `Stock::all()`. Then  you can iterate with a regular foreach loop without filtering the user out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways. first is like @Keepon said: create a relationship between the user and the stock table

2:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$stocks =  Stock::where('user_id','=',$user->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change you index function

```
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{

    $stocks = Stock::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    return view('stock.index', compact('stocks'));
}
```

And than in your blade

```
 @foreach($stocks as $stock)
<tr>
<td>{{$stock->product_name}}</td>
<td>{{$stock->product_code}}</td>
 <td>{{$stock->details}}</td>
  <td>{{$stock->price}}</td>
   <td>{{$stock->cost}}</td>
    <td>{{$stock->quntity}}</td>
<td ><a  href="{{action('StockController@edit', $stock->id)}}" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
</td>
<td>
 <form id="my_form"  method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('StockController@destroy', $stock->id)}}">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
  <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
 </form>
</td>
</tr>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to make a [MODEL RELATIONSHIP](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships).

To make a user and stocks relationship you need to determine what **relationship** would you build.

> In this case I will build a relationship base on what I under stand a **One To Many** relationship

**DATABASE**

**Stocks Migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
  ...
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

It should be look like the above code.
Then in your model you can connect the relationship of **user** and **stocks**

**MODEL**

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function stocks() {
      return $this->hasMany(Stock::class);
    }
}
```

**Stock Model**

```
class Stock extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can query on your controller the user stocks.

**CONTROLLER**

**Stocks Controller**

```
public function index() {
  $stocks = auth()->user()->stocks;

  return view('index', compact('stocks'));
}
```

If you want more example of **eloquent relationship** you can check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Oxfi3DLdkI&list=PLpzy7FIRqpGD0kxI48v8QEVVZd744Phi4&index=14) by Victor

Answer (score 0):

add this function in User Model

```
public function stocks() {
  return $this->hasMany(Stock::class);
}
```

in Stocks Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $stocks = auth()->user()->stocks;
    return view('stock.index', compact('stocks'));
}
```

in index.blade.php

```
@foreach($stocks as $row)
<tr>
<td>{{$row['product_name']}}</td>
<td>{{$row['product_code']}}</td>
 <td>{{$row['details']}}</td>
  <td>{{$row['price']}}</td>
   <td>{{$row['cost']}}</td>
    <td>{{$row['quntity']}}</td>
<td ><a  href="{{action('StockController@edit', $row['id'])}}" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
</td>
<td>
 <form id="my_form"  method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('StockController@destroy', $row['id'])}}">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
  <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
 </form>
</td>
```

@endforeach